# How to allow blank spaces between arguments of a macro

Tags: programming

For example, I would to write `\defpoint [option] (1,2) {A}` instead of 
`\defpoint[option](1,2){A}`. What is the best way to build this kind of macro?

Only the argument [...] is optional and if spaces are allowed between between arguments, spaces are not required (obligatory ?).

And if the user made a syntax error, It might be interesting to note it, how do here?

Comment: It might be handy to specify if you _require_ spaces between arguments or only want to _allow_ them. As the answers already posted show, the two things are slightly different. Also, is the `(...)` argument optional?

Comment: I want only to allow spaces between arguments  and only the argument [..] is optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the standard LaTeX2e method this works with no additional effort:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\defpoint{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\defpoint@aux@i}
    {\defpoint@aux@i[]}%
}
\long\def\defpoint@aux@i[#1]{%
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    {\defpoint@aux@ii{#1}}
    {\ERROR}% As the ( ... ) part is not optional
}
\long\def\defpoint@aux@ii#1(#2)#3{\showtokens{#1:#2:#3}}
\makeatother
\defpoint [option] (1,2) {A}
```

This works for three different reasons for the three arguments!

For the first argument (in square brackets), TeX is skipping spaces after a control sequence and there is nothing that the programmer can do: spaces will always be  allowed here (ignoring rather awkward catcode tricks).

For the optional argument in parentheses, `\@ifnextchar` deliberately skips any spaces it picks up, and so ignores any between `]` and `(`. It is possible to create a version of `\@ifnextchar` which does not skip spaces (indeed, this would be easier that the current implementation). Note that if the `[...]`  argument is not there then TeX is going to skip the spaces after `\defpoint` anyway.

Finally, grabbing the mandatory argument in the standard way again uses TeX's logic. With no additional precautions, `#3` here will be grabbed as the next <balanced text>, which can be seen more simply with something like

```
\def\test#1#2#3{\showtokens{#1:#2:#3}}
\test {A} {B} {C}
```

Comment: What of your favorite pgfkeys solution: `\pgfkeys{/alter/mundus/.code args={ (#2) #3 }{#1#2#3}}`? This allows him to use keys instead of parameters. `[#1]` may be read as n aoptional argument. Also, he could try command keys.

Answer (score 3):

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) allows this by default. See section **1.2 Spacing and optional arguments** of the [`xparse` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf):

> TeX will find the first argument after a function name irrespective of
>   any intervening spaces. This is true for both mandatory and optional
>   arguments.

Barring some specific argument formatting, here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{o d() m}{%
  1: #1; 2: #2; 3: #3
}
\begin{document}
\mycmd[abc](ijk){xyz} \par
\mycmd [abc](ijk){xyz} \par
\mycmd[abc] (ijk){xyz} \par
\mycmd[abc](ijk) {xyz} \par
\mycmd  [abc] (ijk){xyz} \par
\mycmd[abc](ijk)    {xyz} \par
\mycmd[abc]         (ijk){xyz}
\end{document}
```

Syntax errors can be performed on the arguments via boolean tests using, for example, `\IfNoValueTF`.

Comment: We've had discussions about mandatory `(...)` arguments. At the moment, the way we deal with this is just to use an `\IfNoValueTF` test, as you suggest. It would not be too hard to add a mandatory-bracketed argument form: perhaps `b`?

Comment: Why not allow the freedom for mandatory argument delimiters than currently exist with optional ones?

Comment: For mandatory arguments, the usual approach is to pick up TeX <balanced text>. `xparse` is about creating LaTeX2e-like interfaces, and so it is reasonable to stick with the convention of mandatory argument => `{...}`. There's also the more technical question of how you'd specify a mandatory argument with variable delimiters, as you can't pick up `{}` as two arguments (easily). We certainly could add something, probably most easily using the existing `D`-type code and adding a wrapper around the `\IfNoValue` test. However, it's a question of how many real use cases there are.

Comment: (ctd.) For example, you can imagine using `M` for this, with something like `\NewDocumentCommand\foo{oM()m}` for the case in hand. One for LaTeX-L if it seems useful. (Not sure I like using `M` here as the pattern for the other cases is capital letter => default given. So we'd need a good choice of letter. At one stage, we did have `c` for 'co-ordinate pair', but that again is not general.)

Comment: @JosephWright: It all sounds promising! I guess the use case would vary, since most users are familiar with optional `[ ]` and mandatory `{ }` delimiters. I know `pstricks` code, for sure, is filled with optional *and* mandatory `( )` code, while `titlesec` contains a mandatory `[ ]`.

Comment: @Joseph what should xparse do if the mandatory argument is missing? This question never occurs for other argument types.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to point out that using LaTeX's standard macro definition mechanism, you can prepare the option without having to pass the remaining arguments to the helper macro `\defpoint@option`.

The macro `\defpoint` doesn't consume the next tokens and leaves them on the input stream. It simply adds the default option at the start of the token stream if there is no option, and then calls `\defpoint@option`, which consumes all arguments.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\defpoint[1][option]{%
    \defpoint@option[#1]% partial application
}
\def\defpoint@option[#1](#2,#3) #4{% There _has_ to be a space before #4
    Look ma: #1, #2, #3, and #4.
}
\makeatother

\defpoint(1,2) {A}
\defpoint[blah](1,2) {A}
\defpoint(1,2){A} % doesn't work
```